# FileIO exception when introduce the android project

Tags: android, file-io

This is a game project. After introducing the project and run it on virtual machine it has been black frame. There is no game screen.

```
package com.badlogic.androidgames.jumper;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

import com.badlogic.androidgames.framework.FileIO;

public class Settings {
    public static boolean soundEnabled = true;
    public final static int[] highscores = new int[] { 100, 80, 50, 30, 10 };
    public final static String file = ".superjumper";

    public static void load(FileIO files) {
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(files.readFile(file)));  // 这里报异常
            soundEnabled = Boolean.parseBoolean(in.readLine());
            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                highscores[i] = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // :( It's ok we have defaults
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // :/ It's ok, defaults save our day
        } finally {
            try {
                if (in != null)
                    in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    public static void save(FileIO files) {
        BufferedWriter out = null;
        try {
            out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                    files.writeFile(file)));
            out.write(Boolean.toString(soundEnabled));
            out.write("\n");
            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                out.write(Integer.toString(highscores[i]));
                out.write("\n");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
        } finally {
            try {
                if (out != null)
                    out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    public static void addScore(int score) {
        for(int i=0; i < 5; i++) {
            if(highscores[i] < score) {
                for(int j= 4; j > i; j--)
                    highscores[j] = highscores[j-1];
                highscores[i] = score;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I breakpoint and debug the error is `FileNotFoundException`. I can not find `superjumper` in `mmnt/SdCard`.

There is no problem about code. Why it has the exception?

Answer (score 1):

In compilation of your project, the compiler cannot see if the file ".superjumper" exists or not.
There for it will on runtime throw an exception if it can't find it. Which is the case here.

You need to know the exact location of the ".superjumper" file that you want to load.